# Screen Capturing In Java

Tags: java, screen-recording

I have written my own code in java to capture screen and create video from the captured screens. Everything is working as expected, but I am not able to take the no.of frames that I wanted (12 frames) per second, I can take just 5 to 6 at max per second. I have observed that this is because each frame taken is written to file system to use it later to create video. This file writing operation is taking which is hitting the no.of frames to be created in a second. I tried to have captured frames in memory but at some point I am going out of memory. Can somebody suggest how to achieve this. I have tried with multithreading which also did not work.

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: What is your Hardware ? What is the image size ?

Comment: I'm assuming your using something Robot to capture the screen, this is natriously slow, you might like to take a look at [this](http://www.rune-server.org/programming/application-development/387765-directrobot-fast-java-robot-allows-screen-recording.html) for a faster implementation. You could place each frame in queue and use a separate thread to write each frame

Comment: The queue is overwhelmed with captured frames and my program is going out of memory. If I use separate thread to write captured frames and try to remove the written frames from the queue then it is throwing exception related to inconsistent sate. I tried to synchronize that block of the code, still I am not able to go ahead.  Yes, I am using Robot class to capture screen, but it is not about the capturing but about the persisting the captured screens which is where it is going slow.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, How can we create image out of DirectRobot class the one that you have refereed? Do you see, is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Check the bottom part of the post, they poster describes away to convert the `pixel` array from `DirectRobot` to a `BufferedImage`

Comment: First of all that post doesn't seems to be very clear? How can use DirectRobot to capture the screenshot? There is no such method in it to capture image.